# How to calculate the linear momentum on a dumbbell?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, torque

In this picture there is a dumbbell and a mass in motion that hits one of the masses of the dumbbell. Now the problem is I have to find the velocity of the CM and the rotational speed around the CM. My big problem is during the collision, which mass should I consider? I want to apply the conservation of linear momentum, but I can't visualize the total mass of the resting object: the mass should be equal to one of the dumbbell masses or the sum of both dumbbell masses.

![dumbbell]https://i.imgsafe.org/a5263f119e.jpg

Comment: The solution to such a problems requires a little more information than you have given.  Is the collision between masses $3m$ and $m$ elastic or does mass $3m$ stick to mass $m$?

Comment: You should treat the collusion to be happening at the center of mass and a torque to be acting on the mass $m$ during the collusion. You can obtain the angular impulse from the linear impulse since you know the distance between mass $m$ and the axis of rotation (center of mass of the dumbell in this case). Impulse = Change in momentum = Change in angular momentum * distance between COM and mass $m$. If you'd let me know what type of collusion the objects are making (the very same question Farcher asked), then I can furnish a neat answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, the additional information is that the mass that is moving and collides continues to move in the same direction after the collision, and the collision is elastic. Yashas, but why can we do that? For instance, if I have a marble and a bowling bowl connected through a rod, shouldn't we consider only one of the masses, depending on where it is hit? Also, if we hit the CM, the body wouldn't rotate, is that correct? "If the force is applied at the center of mass, the system moves in the direction of the force without rotating", quoted from Serway&Jewett... Thank you for your answers

Comment: I added a solution. Give me 2-3 minutes to update it with the new info (elastic collision).

Comment: solution updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

First of all, I shall assume that the system is kept on a horizontal plane so as to simplify the calculations.

Secondly, I shall assume that the line joining the mass $m$ and $M$ is perpendicular to the direction of motion of mass $3m$.

Thirdly, I shall assume that the spheres to be point objects (in other words, you can consider it to be a perfect head-on collision).

My sign convention will be as follows:

1. The positive x-axis is in the direction of the velocity of the mass $3m$
2. The positive y-axis is in the direction from the sphere with mass $M$ to the sphere with mass $m$.

Before we start, let us review some important facts about the center of mass of a system. The center of mass velocity changes IF AND ONLY IF there is some center of mass acceleration. The center of mass has an acceleration IF AND ONLY IF there is a net unbalanced force acting on the 'system'.

The sphere with mass $3m$ collides with the sphere of mass $m$ head-on. Now consider the system after the collision. Is there any net force acting on the system? There is no net force acting on the system which means that the center of mass velocity does NOT change the direction rather it keeps going straight. We know for certain, that the dumbbell is going to rotate. Since the center of mass velocity moves in a straight line, it implies that the rotation of the dumbbell is about the center of mass of the dumbbell.

In what direction does it move? This can be understood by using the law of conservation of momentum. Initially, only the sphere with mass $3m$ is moving along the x-axis. The overall momentum of the 3 body system is along the positive x-axis which means the overall momentum of the system after the collision must also be along the positive x-axis which means the center of mass of the dumbell travels along the positive x-axis.

During the collision, some of the linear momenta of the mass $3m$ is transferred to the dumbbell, i.e: center of mass momentum (the amount depends on the type of collision, elastic or inelastic). The collusion is as if it was a collusion of the mass $3m$ with the center of mass of the dumbbell. There is one exception to that analogy, the collision causes a torque which acts along the positive x-axis through mass $m$ which wouldn't have happened in the case of two point collusions. Solving the problem using torque simply creates a mess. A better way off would be to use the change in linear momentum of the center of mass, i.e: impulse and convert it to angular impulse. Since we know that the rotation of the dumbbell is going to happen about the center of mass, you have the distance between the mass $m$ and the center of mass of the dumbbell using which you can inter-convert between linear and angular impulse.

$$Linear Impulse =  change in linear momentum = F_{avg} \Delta{t}$$

$$Angular Impulse = Change in angular momentum = \tau_{avg}\Delta{t}$$

We know that 
$$\vec{\tau_{avg}} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F_{avg}}$$

In our case, the impulse is along the positive x-axis and the line joining the mass $m$ and the center of mass is along the positive y-axis, the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F_{avg}}$ is 90 degrees. Hence, the following formula will suffice,

Change in angular momentum is equal to the angular momentum gained since it was at rest initially.

$$J = \tau_{avg}\Delta{t} = r(F_{avg}\Delta{t}) = rI$$

where J is the angular impulse and I is the linear impulse.

From the linear impulse, you can calculate the velocity of the center of mass and from the angular impulse, you can find the angular velocity.

$$(M + m)\vec{v_{com}} = I$$
$$(moment-of-inertia)\omega = J$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got it! So basically what you are saying is that it doesn't matter where the force is applied in terms of force, it only matters in terms of torque, that is, we can consider the **3m** particle to hit the COM to determine the velocity but we cannot consider the colision to be at the COM, is that correct? Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where the force acts when you are dealing with the motion of the center of mass. The direction matters only when you are going to deal with rotation  because you will need the radius vector from the axis of rotation to the point where the force acts to find the torque/angular impulse.

Comment: You should've know it from the definition of center of mass. If you differentiate the center of mass equation twice, you get the acceleration. multiply each term by its corresponding elemental mass, you get the force. From that, you should've understood that the sum of forces acting all over the body will give a COM acceleration as if all the forces were acting on the COM.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I guess I couldn't understand why the point of application of the force didn't matter, but from definition it makes perfect sense because it is the sum of all the Fi=mi.ai. It is also because I am now learning the concept of torque and it created some conflicts. Thank you!